# Fluentd installation instructions for AWS Elasticsearch Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kubernetes, elasticsearch-5

We use AWS Elasticsearch Service. We would like to install fluentd to our Kubernetes cluster. Fluentd sends logs to AWS Elasticsearch Service. It there any instructions on how to do it? At this link, https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd, it shows steps on sending the logs to an Elasticsearch Pod. It means the elasticsearch is installed inside the Kubernetes cluster.

The link above shows make changes in fluentd-daemonset-elasticsearch.yaml (see below) for elasticsearch pod. What configuration changes I need to make for the AWS elasticsearch service?

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  ...
spec:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: quay.io/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "elasticsearch-logging"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
            ......
```

Comment: You could try the solution from this [GitHub link](https://github.com/bshetti/fluentd-helm-vke).  And also some explanation from this [article](https://medium.com/faun/sending-kubernetes-logs-to-amazon-elasticsearch-service-8fb8f18ac35d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the required connectivity. For example, Kubernetes and Elasticsearch on the same [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html) or if in different VPCs you have [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) configured.

Additionally, you have the firewall rules ([Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)) to allow port `9200` from Kubernetes to the Elasticsearch cluster.

It should be straight forward (just point the configs to the AWS Elasticsearch cluster endpoint):

```sh
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  ...
spec:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: quay.io/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "vpc-domain-name-identifier.region.es.amazonaws.com" 
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
            ......
```

This is if you are using VPCs. You can also use the public Elasticsearch endpoint too if you configured your cluster that way. (But it's less secure since you are going through the public cloud). Something like this:

```sh
https://search-domain-name-identifier.region.es.amazonaws.com
```

✌️

Comment: Hi Rico, it works. Thank you. Follow up question. I deployed fluentd as Daemonset in kube-system namespace. The kubectl log pod and kubectl describe pod show no error, nor warning. We deploy our csc application to csc namespace. In order to collect log of csc, do I need to deploy fluentd in the csc namespace as well?

Comment: No, it should collect from all namespaces.

Comment: Hi Rico, we have third party apps installed in our cluster. Things like datadog, premetheus, grafana, etc. We would like not to send logs of these application to the elasticsearch. We do not want to send logs of kube-system, nor kube-public. We only want to send the logs of csc application to elasticsearch. I deployed fluentd as daemonset in the csc namespace. But, it send entire cluster logs. How do I only send logs of csc?

Comment: You have to change the config file to collect a pattern that just comes from that namespace. For example: https://www.zebrium.com/blog/how-fluentd-collects-kubernetes-metadata. From the security perspective, you can use RBAC: https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter/issues/88 or you can just Filebeat instead of Fluentd https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/add-kubernetes-metadata.html